# Comma operator in JS: syntax error expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know what's wrong with my code

```js
function getItems() {
  onSnapshot(collection(db, "todo-items"), (snapshot) => {
      setTodoItems(snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>{
          return {
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data()
          }
      })
  })
}
```

',' expected.ts(1005)

I get this error and i don't know how to fix it.
I tried to fix it.

Comment: Is that a linter warning? A compiler error message? Where (in what tool) do you see that message? What line/column does it point at in your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a closing parenthesis for `setTodoItems` functions.

```
function getItems() {
  onSnapshot(collection(db, "todo-items"), (snapshot) => {
    setTodoItems(
      snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        };
      }) 
    );  // <- HERE
  });
}
```